# SockJS + Stomp + SpringBoot = Issue

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

I have an application with a page that subscribe a websocket endpoint with this:

```
 var socket = new SockJS("/hello");
            stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
            stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
                stompClient.subscribe('/topic/nextticket', function (ws_response) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(ws_response.body);
                    ....
                });
            });
```

This app run on Raspberry and all works fine when the raspberry is connected on internet. But in a local network (no Internet) I have this

[image]

My backend conf is:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:/etc/app.properties")
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
class MessageBroker extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    Environment env

    @Override
    void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic")
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
    }



    @Override
    void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {

        def ip = env.getProperty("kiosk.ip") ? env.getProperty("kiosk.ip") as String : "192.168.1.90"

        registry.addEndpoint("/hello")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .withSockJS()
                .setClientLibraryUrl("http://${ip}:8080/js/sockjs.js")


    }
}
```

I don't understand why have a CORS (I suppose) problem.. And the page reload forever.

Thanks in advance

Luis

Answer (score 0):

I had this CORS behaviour in my application whenever I used a specific IP.

**application.properties**

```
server.address: 192.168.1.90
```

**After removing server.address from the application.properties** the application worked as expected. If somebody knows the cause of this please let me know. I would have expected that

```
registry.setAllowedOrigins("*")
```

would remove all CORS behaviour as [document here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-server-allowed-origins)